# CiviCRM Spark Localization Change

Tags: language

I'am a totally beginner. After signing-up to CiviCRM Spark for evualating I expected the web-Site to be in German, but it's all in english.  How Can I change the language to German?

[image: This is the requested screen shot]

Comment: Uli - may be worth familiarising yourself with documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/installation-and-basic-set-up/#localization as it should be able to help with such questions

Answer (score 1):

Uli, Welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange.

You can change the language by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Localization >> Languages, Currency, Locations

Change the default language to German.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thank you but your advice didn't work, In the menue German aleady was selected, but english is active. Below there isa check box "Multiple language support, which can't be selected.

Comment: Please be aware that I'm using CiviCRM Spark hosting Platform and nit CiviCRM as it is.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of that Languages page to your original question?

Comment: I added the screenshot. Hopefully it will be seen, I'am a newcomer for forum conversation as well